# String to DateTime Conversion when updating on the field directly in Apex

Tags: apex, datetime, wrapper-class

```
for (Lead__c l: leads) {
      l.Last_updated__c = String.ValueOf(leadResponce.leadData.lastUpdated);
}
```

how can I converted the value coming form the JSON from the wrappers while updating a field directly like this?

```
DateTime.valueOf(String.ValueOf(leadResponce.leadData.lastUpdated));
```

Above is an error of datatype conversion, which I am aware but I am trying to learn and see if I can get this in one line without creating another variable to store the value and then convert.

Comment: Is the data already a string, or is it a date?

Comment: the JSON data that is coming back from is a timestamp something like 2017-01-10T14:53:55.000+0000 which is consumed inside the wrapper ```leadResponce```

```lastUpdated``` is defined as a string inside the wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the JSON property to a DateTime:

```
public DateTime lastUpdated;
```

The JSON parser is smart enough to use this standard datetime format to an internal format you can use in Apex.

You can also parse it directly if you want to:

```
DateTime lastUpdated = (DateTime)JSON.deserialize('"'+leadResponce.leadData.lastUpdated+'"', DateTime.class);
```

Note that we had to wrap it back into a string to get it to parse. For this reason, I strongly advise you refactor your wrapper to just use a DateTime directly.